# How to create public activities in getstream-io

Tags: getstream-io

I want to broadcast some activities such as "User joined" for all members to see. Currently I have a flat `user` feed. Is there a way to push an activity so that it's visible by everyone?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the TO field to add an activity to a global feed. For example:

```
// Instantiate a feed using feed class 'user' and user id '1'
var user1 = client.feed('user', '1');
// Add an activity to the feed
var activity = {"to": ["user:global"], "actor": "User:1", "verb": "pin", "object": "Place:42", "target": "Board:1"};
user1.addActivity(activity)
// activity is added to both user:1 as well as user:global
```

Alternatively you could have 1 editorial account, that is followed by all your users.